# Tryng to add scrolling feature to absolute div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div which represents a basket for an e-commerce website. This div is absolute positioned and fades into the screen when the user clicks the basket icon. I have deactivated the main page's scrolling so that the sole focus is on the basket div once it emerges onto the screen.

What I am having a problem with is this; if the user adds enough items to the basket, the div expands in height, off the screens view, and the user can not scroll down to view all items in the basket. The items are added to the basket through a click event.

I want the div to be restrictred to a certain height. But because it is an absolute positioned element, I do not know how exactly to go about adding a scrolling feture. I have added a parent div with the position of relative but that still doesnt work.

Thanks for the helpful responses in advance!

CODE:

```css
#bakset-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

#basket-content {
  z-index: 10000;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: black;
  width: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 10%;
}

#basket-content ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 2em;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  width: 90%;
}

#basket-content ul li {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
}

#basket-headings {
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

#basket-headings li {
  background-color: #346b25;
  padding: 0.2em;
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
}

#basket-content {
  display: none;
}

#basket-content .shopnow {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="basket-container">

<div id="basket-content">


    <h1>YOUR SHOPPING BASKET</h1>

    <ul id="basket-headings">

      <li>PRODUCT</li>
      <li>QTY</li>
      <li>SUBTOTAL</li>

    </ul>

    <button id="checkoutcomplete">COMPLETE ORDER</button>

    <span class="close-window">CLOSE WINDOW</span>


  </div>

</div>
```

I have added an image of what the problem looks like. As you can see, my 'complete order' button is going beyond the screen. If I add one or two more products to the div, it will expand, the user can not scroll down to view the button or the rest of the content.

[image: You can see from the image that my 'checkout' button is starting to go beyond the screen]

Comment: use `max-height` property

Comment: Where shall I put the max-height property? On the parent div? I have done so and nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: hey jimmy it seems your code is not working in a fiddle. Can you update your code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so that it will be easy for us to give you a better solution.

Comment: Hi Benjamin. Thanks for the response and suggesstion. Do I need to register to use jsfiddle? I am in the process of doing just that. Please bare with me.

Comment: Its not necessary to register

Comment: @benajmin I cant figure out why its not showing on jsfiddle...would a screenshot of the screen and problem be helpful?

Comment: Yes please pass

Comment: @Benjamin screenshot has been added

Comment: You would need to set the height of the absolute `div` (either `height` or `max-height` would do) and, to enable the internal scrollbars, set `overflow-y: auto`, also on the absolute `div`.

Comment: ah thank you so much @Haroldo_OK this works great!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `max-height` of `calc(100vh - 10%)` to your identifier `basket-container` with a `overflow: scroll`. It should be working fine.

```
#basket-container {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 10%);
    overflow: auto;
}
```